# Erro Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method from the type

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer esse exercício e ele retorna esse erro:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method triplo(int)
> from the type MinhasFuncoes

```
public class MinhasFuncoes {

    public int triplo(int numero){
        return numero * 3;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println(triplo(3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que declarar o método de acesso da função como static.

```
public static int triplo(int numero){
    return numero * 3;
}
```

Caso não queira utilizar como um método estático você deve criar uma instância de um objeto para poder utilizar o método `tripo`, que o a sua API do objeto `MinhasFunções` expõe. Segue um exemplo:

```
public class MinhasFuncoes {

public int triplo(int numero){
    return numero * 3;
}
public static void main(String[]args) {
    MinhasFuncoes mf = new MinhasFuncoes();
    System.out.println(mf.triplo(2));     
}
```

Comment: Valeu!! obrigado